# Create a form for Send email from dashboard wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I need a contact form to put on one of the WordPress dashboard pages.

This form has two fields.
The first field is where I want to enter the recipient's email address.
The second field is a text box where I write the text of the email.
I want the text of the email to go to the email address that I specified in the first field by pressing the send button.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin, [Send Email From Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/send-email-from-admin/)

With this plugin, you can send emails to your users.